# import pandas and import numpy result in AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'core'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, attributeerror

I have an `anaconda distribution` of `python`.

I was tinkering with `plot.ly` and cufflinks (I installed via `pip`) and I upgraded `numpy/pandas` via `pip` as well. Probably a stupid thing to do outside of using `conda install`.

In any case, I restarted my machine and now `import pandas` and `import numpy` result in the error below.

I even did an update to conda via:

```
conda update --prefix C:\Users\shal\Anaconda3 anaconda
```

The problem persists even after that update.

My python version is:

```
3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:49:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

UPDATE:

- I re-installed `numpy` via `conda install numpy` and the problem persists.
- I even did a `conda clean -all` and the problem persists.
- Removed plot.ly via pip uninstall plot.ly

Looking closer at where the Error occured:

```
---> 11 import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
     12 from numpy.core.numeric import asarray, asanyarray, array, isnan, \
     13                 obj2sctype, zeros

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'core'
```

There is a directory named `core` in the numpy folder. In it there is a `numeric.py` file, which seems to be what is trying to be imported in line 11. I'm not sure why the error occurs at all since I do have a directory named `core` in the `numpy` folder and the file that it is trying to access i.e. `numeric.py`.

The question then becomes what directory is the call to `import numpy as np` looking for the module to be in?

Anyone have any ideas on what may be the problem and what I can do to fix?

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4ee716103900> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy as np

C:\Users\blah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>()
    140         return loader(*packages, **options)
    141 
--> 142     from . import add_newdocs
    143     __all__ = ['add_newdocs',
    144                'ModuleDeprecationWarning',

C:\Users\blah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py in <module>()
     11 from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
     12 
---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     14 
     15 ###############################################################################

C:\Users\blah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py in <module>()
      6 from numpy.version import version as __version__
      7 
----> 8 from .type_check import *
      9 from .index_tricks import *
     10 from .function_base import *

C:\Users\blah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py in <module>()
      9            'common_type']
     10 
---> 11 import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
     12 from numpy.core.numeric import asarray, asanyarray, array, isnan, \
     13                 obj2sctype, zeros

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'core'
```

Comment: check whether you have another files named `core.py`...

Comment: I have a folder named "C:\Users\blah\Anaconda3\pkgs\numpy-1.10.4-py35_0\Lib\site-packages\numpy\ma" AND "C:\Users\blah\Anaconda3\pkgs\numpy-1.10.4-py35_0\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils" where core.py exists. Question now is, is this the correct directory where it should be? I'm not sure what directory import is expecting the file to be in. Why do I have 2 copies of core.py in 2 separate locations?

Comment: both of them are different size files. The one in /ma directory is 237 KB and the one in /distut‌​ils is 8 KB.

Comment: But no core.py in the numpy\core directory. C:\Users\blah\Anaconda3\pkgs\numpy-1.10.4-py35_0\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core.

Comment: It seems from the Error message that it can't find the core directory. Because line 11 its trying to import numeric.py which does exist in the core directory. Question is what directory is import numpy looking for the module data?

Comment: check for `numeric...` in the `C:\Users\blah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy` instead of `C:\Users\blah\Anaconda3\pkgs\...`

Comment: I do find numeric.py in 'C:\Users\blah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy'. Am I at a point where I should wipe out my entire anaconda distribution and re-install?

Comment: i think it makes sense

Comment: I re-installed conda and now everything is fine. Not going to mix pip with conda package manager ever again. :-)